# Creating a matrix of checkboxes which supports post back in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to think of a way to manage the selection of a matrix of values via view models in MVC 5.

I have a list of companies and a list of roles. The roles are the same for each company. What I want is to output a matrix of companies/roles with a checkbox for each combination. This allows the user to select which role the person will have for each company.

I can render the output with nested foreach loops but I can't help but think there's a better way to achieve this with MVC and Editor Templates.

Below is a crude example of the layout. So every company is output as a column and every role is output as a row. A checkbox for each company is then output into every row.

```
Company/Role  COMPANY1 COMPANY2 COMPANY3
ROLE1            [X]       []      []
ROLE2            []        []      [X]   
ROLE3            []        []      []
```

The added complexity is being able to handle postback. My view model structure is currently..

```
public class RequestViewModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public List<CompanyAccessViewModel> CompanyAccessViewModels { get; set; }
    }

public class CompanyAccessViewModel
    {
        public int Company { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
        public List<Company> ListCompanies { get; set; }
        public List<Role> ListRoles { get; set; }
        public List<CompanyAccessRoleViewModel> CompanyAccessRoleViewModels { get; set; }
    }

public class CompanyAccessRoleViewModel
    {
        public Guid AccessRequirementId { get; set; }
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Role { get; set; }
    }
```

ListCompanies is the list of all the companies.
ListRoles is a list of all the roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, start with a view model(s) to represent what you want to display/edit.

```
public class RoleVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyVM> Companies { get; set; }
}
public class CompanyVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Role> roles = db.Roles;
    IEnumerable<Company> companies = db.Companies;
    List<RoleVM> model = roles.Select(x => new RoleVM()
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Name = x.Name,
        Companies = companies.Select(y => new CompanyVM()
        {
            ID = y.ID,
            Name = y.Name
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
    // For editing existing roles, set the IsSelected property
    // of the respective CompanyVM to true
    return View(model);
}
```

and the view

```
@model List<RoleVM>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Company/Role</th>
                @foreach(var company in Model.FirstOrDefault().Companies)
                {
                    <th>@company.Name</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Model[i].Name
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
                    </td>
                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Companies.Count; j++)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Companies[j].ID)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Companies[j].Name)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].Companies[j].IsSelected)
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>    
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

which will the post to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<RoleVM> model)
{
    // To get the companies for each role
    foreach (var role in model)
    {
        var selectedCompanies = role.Companies.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
```

---

Note that using nested `foreach` loops would never have bound correctly when submitting your form (you need to use `for` loops). If you want to use EditorTemplates (your properties can be `IEnumerable<T>` rather that `IList<T>`, then create a partial in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RoleVM.cshtml`

```
@model RoleVM
<tr>
    <td>
        @Model.Name
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    </td>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Companies)
</tr>
```

and another for `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/CompanyVM.cshtml`

```
@model CompanyVM
<td>
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
     @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
     @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsSelected)
</td>
```

and the main view would be

```
@model List<RoleVM>
.... // as above
<tbody>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m)
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just got to add in the top layer view model and then the automapper logic!